# How to search data from 3 (multiple) table in laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[image: table]

I want to make search to show speaker where the input contain speaker name and also show speaker where the input contain `topicname` that the speaker had

I try to make

```
$speaker = Speaker::where ('name','like','%'.$search.'%')->orWhere ........
```

What should I make in `andWhere` clause?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is you wanna search either by speaker name or speakers topic name

heres my code for that assuming you have relationships setup between your models:

```
    $speaker = Speaker::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhereHas('Detail', function(Builder $query) use ($search){
            $query->whereHas('Topic', function(Builder $subQuery) use ($search){
                $subQuery->where('topicname', 'like','%'. $search . '%');
            });
        })->get();
```

reference : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 0):

First join  table

`$speaker = Speaker::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%")`

`->orWhere('topicname', 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%") ->get();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding relations between Speaker, Detail, Topic models.
Add this to Speaker model:

```
public function detail()
   {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Speaker', 'speakerID');
     }
    
public function topic()
           {
            return Topic::find(this->detail->topicID);
           }
```

add this to Topic model

```
 public function detail()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Detail');
    }
```

and to access data you do it like this

```
$speaker->detail   -to get detail info 
$speaker->topic()  -to get topic info
```

and  to search on database is easy like this:
if you have the speaker name:

```
$speaker = Speaker::where('name','=',$searchName)->first();
```

if you have the topic name:

```
$topic = Topic::where('topicname',=',$searchTopicName)->first();
$detail = topic->detail;
$speaker = Speaker::find($detail->speakerID);
```

so you have all infos you need on all three $topic, $detail, $speaker.

and if you want to use querybuilder you can do like this:

```
$speaker =Detail::join('speaker', 'detail.speakerID', '=','speaker.detID')
                ->join('topic', 'detail.topicID', '=','topic.topicID')
                ->where('speaker.name', '=', $searchName)
                ->orWhere('topic.topicname', '=', $searchTopicName)
                ->get();
```